# Finding the best grasp position or point?

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a point cloud data, where the detected objects are bounded by the bounding box. We were planning to suck(grasp) it from the top plane of the object. How do I go about determining the co-ordinates for grasping on any surface using PCL? I am new to programming, any help extended here is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Grasp detection is an open problem with new state of the art solutions appearing every month or so. As far as I know PCL has no ready to use solution for that. So, you'd better google for publications with newest solutions in this area.
Here are the articles I found useful for me:

- [agile_grasp](http://wiki.ros.org/agile_grasp) ROS node and "[Using Geometry to Detect Grasps](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.03100.pdf)."
- [Real-Time Grasp Detection Using Convolutional Neural Networks](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.3128)
- [Deep Learning for Detecting Robotic Grasps](http://pr.cs.cornell.edu/deepgrasping/)
- [GraspIt!](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cmatei/graspit/)

Hope this helps.